# I need to hide the arguments from jenkins log

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

I need to build docker image with set of attributes through Jenkins, i also need to pass my private key as a argument, but while build the image i am getting the private key in my Jenkins log. I need to get rid of it and i need only the image build logs, anyone please help me on this

```
docker build --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)-t ${REGISTRY}/${APPLICATION_NAME}:PR-${CHANGE_ID} .
```

Comment: See if this helps : https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs

Comment: Your private key will be unencrypted in `docker history` and there for anyone to see if they `docker run` a debugging shell.  You shouldn't pass ssh keys into your build sequence like this at all.  Have your Jenkins pipeline check out all of the required dependencies itself before it builds the Docker image.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @David

> You shouldn't pass ssh keys into your build sequence like this at all

But to answer your question, modify the bash script and it will not display the content your ssh-key.

```
set +x
docker build --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)" -t ssha .
set -x
```

you will not able to see the ssh_key during the build time, but it will be set, you can verify

```
docker run --rm ssha bash -c "cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not entirely comfortable w/advocating "workarounds". Could you close your response w/”but this is NOT the best approach"?

Answer (score 2):

Try using MaskPasswordWrapper, it would successfully  mask all the variables that are specified throughout the jenkins console log.

Plugin Link: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin

```
script{
    san7ket = 'lololol'
    wrap([$class: 'MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper', varMaskRegexes: [[regex: '(.)']], varPasswordPairs: [[var: 'sjagtap', var:'a']]]) {
    // some block
    echo san7ket
    echo a
}    
}
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] wrap
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
********************************************************
[Pipeline] echo
****************************************************************************************
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // wrap
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
```